# Sum unique values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with documents like so:

```json
{
    "id": ...,
    "value": ...,
}
```

It is denormalized, so the same `id` will appear multiple times, but they'll all have the same `value` with each.

I want to sum the distinct values, i.e. the equivalent of this SQL:

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM (
    SELECT id, value
    FROM index
    GROUP BY id, value
) inner
```

Is it possible to do this in Elasticsearch? I tried using the `sum_buckets` aggregate, like so:

```json
{
 "aggs": {
  "uniq_id": {
    "terms": {"field": "id"},
    "aggs": {
      "avg_value": {
        "avg": {
            "field": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sum_value": {
    "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "uniq_id>avg_value"
    }
  }
 },
 "size": 0
}
```

But there is no way to sum all buckets exhaustively, you are limited to the `size` of the `terms` aggregate. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you have multiple documents with the same `id` and `value` ?
Like `doc1:{id: 1, value: 1}`, `doc2:{id: 1, value: 1}`, `doc3:{id: 3, value: xx}` and `doc4:{id: 3, value: yy}`

And you would like to know per `id` how many `value` values do you have ?
so for `id: 1` -> `1`, `id: 3` -> `2`

Comment: Or is it that: `id:1, value: 1` -> `2`, `id:3, value:xx` -> `xx` and `id:3, value:yy` -> `yy` ?

Comment: Your first q: doc3's value and doc4's value would always be the same, as they have the same id.  If the value there was 5, I am looking for `SUM(1 + 5)`, where 1 was the value for id 1, and 5 was the value for id 3.

Comment: Put another way, there was originally a normalized table of `id, value`, but it got denormalized into this index. I want to do SUM queries on what the original normalized table was like, i.e. `SELECT SUM(value) FROM normalized WHERE id IN (...)`

Comment: I think this can be solution for you. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/66459 if ES gives a support for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) parameter ..

One example is below for top_hits

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_values": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "value": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "sum_value": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Here is the modified version for your case with sum_buckets and top_hits

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_value": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": ["value"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_value": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "uniq_id>top_value>hits>hits>value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `terms` aggregate has an upper limit of `search.max_bucket` results, which means I can't get a complete aggregate.

Answer (score -1):

Before taking a deep dive into complex aggregations, designing them(much more important),
Why not get acquainted with the [SQL Translate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html), which allows you to simply convert whatever sql query you desire into elasticsearch query?
you have something similar in kibana.  
This way you'll get what you need faster, and get acquainted better with the elastic query dsl.

Comment: The SQL translate API does not support the query above - `Nested aggregations in sub-selects are not supported.`